# Is there a better way to say someone is "great at painting landscapes/portraits"

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

I would like to be able to praise someone for their paintings but am entirely lacking in the necessary vocabulary. I would welcome some pointers.

Comment: "Mary is a talented portrait artist." (Or "landscape artist"; your question title doesn't agree with the question body.)

Comment: Assuming they're landscape paintings, and borrowing nnnnnn's Mary :-) . . . 
You could mention the radiant genius of her brushwork, the transcendent splendour of her early "Meadow", the luminous plangency of her recent "Midden" and so on.
Or you could say, "Her work transits the liminal space curated by the male gaze, taking a deep dive into - and interrogating - the gendered narratives that bleed into the discourse _around_ exteriority: landscape qua lived reality."
[If they're portraits, just change the ending to "...interiority: portraiture qua lived reality."]

Comment: If her work is in some way different from that of others, you say, "She has torn up the rule book."